# How to add a calculated "ID" to a button in a @foreach loop - ASP.NET Web Pages Razor

Tags: asp.net, razor

I have a @foreach loop for a blog displaying all posts on my page. I have a button at the bottom of each post and when clicked I want that particular post to animate. My logic is within my @foreach loop to add a different ID to each button so I can perform an animation depending on which post is selected...please help

```
@{


    foreach(var post in posts){
        <div class="userPosts">
            @post.FirstName<br /><br />
            @post.LastName<br /><br />
            @post.Subject<br><br>
           <button id="">click here</button>
        </div>

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well if I understand that right , you need just to sign the id of every post in every Loop for each button, wich means `<button id="@post.Id"></button>`

Comment: Thanks I'm going to pull the ID as well and make that the button ID

Answer (score 0):

Use regular for loop instead foreach

```
@for(var i = 0; i< posts.Count; i++)
{
       <div class="userPosts">
            @post.FirstName<br /><br />
            @post.LastName<br /><br />
            @post.Subject<br><br>
           <button id="@i">click here</button>
        </div>
}
```

If you must use foreach you will have to add an index variable

```
@{
int index = 0;
foreach(var post in posts){
        <div class="userPosts">
            post.FirstName<br /><br />
            post.LastName<br /><br />
            post.Subject<br><br>
           <button id="@index">click here</button>
        </div>
        index++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if there is already ID property in the `posts`:

```
@{
    foreach(var post in posts){
        <div class="userPosts">
            @post.FirstName<br /><br />
            @post.LastName<br /><br />
            @post.Subject<br><br>
           <button id="@post.ID">click here</button>
        </div>

    }
```

Otherwise:

```
@for(var i = 0; i< posts.Count; i++)
{
       <div class="userPosts">
            @posts[i].FirstName<br /><br />
            @posts[i].LastName<br /><br />
            @posts[i].Subject<br><br>
           <button id="@i">click here</button>
        </div>
}
```